# Getting uploaded file path from apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I can get the name of the file, the size of the file and the script which have uploaded the file from mod-security logs. But I was creating a script which needs exact path where the uploaded file is kept by apache after the uploading is complete. Is there any way to find this location through Apache logs or any other way.

Comment: What scripting language are you using?

Comment: How does the uploading work? A form, a script...how?